# C++ Regex find distinct word in a string where all words have the same length

Tags: c++, regex, unique, distinct-values

First of all, if this is a duplicate, please point an answer to the exact question.

I'm trying to find the only, unique (non repetitive) word in a string using Regex. All the words have the very same length of 10.

innovationinnovationmotivation**appearance**motivationinnovation

I need to get the word **appearance** and only it. Is it possible to achieve this with Regex? I have several working non regex solutions, but I'm looking for a faster one.

Comment: A non regex solution is likely to be faster than a regex one tbh.

Comment: @melpomene I'm not sure that I understand your question. The length of all the words is 10 chars always. If the sentence is abbbbbbbbaabbbbbbbba it will contain 2 words: 2 x abbbbbbbba. Is this what you are asking?

Comment: I've removed my comment as I had indeed misunderstood what you're trying to do.

Comment: @melpomene yes, there is only one distinct word there.

Comment: Following `^(?:.{10})*?(.{10})(?!(?:.{10})*\1)` finds first occurrence not repeated afterward [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/2WLAvE/2/). Don't know yet how to remove the other way too.

Comment: I got it to work with spaces. Someone refine the following code to ignore spaces. `(\w{10})(?!.*\1)` works with the current string `innovation innovation motivation appearance motivation innovation`. [*Regex101 Link*](https://regex101.com/r/3f0vPy/1)

Comment: @Alex: As me it just found the first "word" without future repetition try `"word1 word1 word2"`, it would find last occurrence of `word1`.